# Additional index in a view which hits an indexed table

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Say I have a **table T** with 10+ columns and a **view V** which selects 4 of those columns. Doing a

```
select columnA from V where columnB=x and columnC=y and (columnD like '%z%')
```

I also have a covering non-clustered index (covers both *select* and *where* columns). The problem is the part in brackets - having wildcards on both sides effectively makes the column sort irrelevant.

Will I benefit from creating a new, possibly clustered/full-text index of the view? I know this will probably materialize it. Is there any other negative effect other than the extra space requirements?

Any other ideas how to do wildcard searches?

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan to see if your index is actually used?

If it is already used, I don't see why indexed view should help in this scenario: the '%' before 'z' will still make seek by columnD impossible, whether the index is clustered or not.
Fulltext index will not help with the wildcard before 'z' either.

How big is the table T anyway? Maybe just filtering by columnB and columnC will be selective enough to not bother with index on columnD?

Comment: Yes, I verified with the execution plan - the index is indeed used. My idea was to have a full-text indexed view on top of the table and use something like CONTAINS(columnD, 'z') which I think should work like %z%.

Comment: Well, fulltext search in SQL only supports asterisk after the phrase, not before.
Please check here the definition and description of prefix_term: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As helix mentioned in the comments to the question, full-text search with a wildcard in front is not allowed so full-text search (and any additional views it might be based on) is of little help in this case.

It also appeared that creating a new (even materialized) view brings no performance improvement.

Working solution: just parallelize the comparison as much as possible. SQL Server's MAXDOP (MAX Degree Of Parallelism) gave really good results - near linear improvement.
[MAXDOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094.aspx)
[Query hints for MAXDOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)